# getBlock('cart_sidebar') is null on Checkout_Cartcontroller override

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ajax

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/

It seems it's working, it adds the product to the cart, but it don't update it, instead it's returning an error that can't do toHtml on a boolean.

I followed this error to this line:

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class Feliu_Ajaxcart_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        ... //lot of code omitted
        $this->loadLayout();
        $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
        $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
        ... //lot of code omitted
    }
}
```

And $sidebar_block is always `null`, so the toHtml() is returning an error. If I change the line `$sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();` to `$sidebar = '<div>' . $sidebar_block . '</div>';` then there is no error, but shopping cart is not updating because is replacing the cart by an empty div.

This is the javascript in the view to make the ajax call and replace the cart by the updated one:

```
//mytheme/template/catalog/product/viewphtml
//<![CDATA[
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');

productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;

        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        //Start of our new ajax code
        if(!url){
            url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
        }
        url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajaxcart/index");
        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
        data += '&isAjax=1';
        jQuery('#ajax_loader').show();
        try {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                    console.log(data.status + ": " + data.message);
                    console.log(data); // here I see what's returning the controller function add
                    if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
                        jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                    }
                    if(jQuery('.header .links')){
                        jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, response){
                    // will fire when timeout is reached
                    console.log("timeout is reached");
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(response);
                    jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 6000
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("fail");
            console.log(e);
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

and the config.xml of the module

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Feliu_Ajaxcart>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Feliu_Ajaxcart>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <feliu_ajaxcart>
            <class>Feliu_Ajaxcart_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>feliu_ajaxcart_resource</resourceModel>
        </feliu_ajaxcart>
        <feliu_ajaxcart_resource>
            <class>Feliu_Ajaxcart_Model_Resource</class>
        </feliu_ajaxcart_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <feliu_ajaxcart>
            <class>Feliu_Ajaxcart_Block</class>
        </feliu_ajaxcart>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <feliu_ajaxcart>
            <class>Feliu_Ajaxcart_Helper</class>
        </feliu_ajaxcart>
    </helpers>
    <resources>
        <feliu_ajaxcart_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Feliu_Ajaxcart</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </feliu_ajaxcart_setup>
        <feliu_ajaxcart_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </feliu_ajaxcart_write>
        <feliu_ajaxcart_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </feliu_ajaxcart_read>
    </resources>
    <rewrite>
        <feliu_ajaxcart> <!--This can be any unique id -->
            <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>  <!-- the URL which u want to override-->
            <to>/ajaxcart/index/</to>  <!-- destination url -->
        </feliu_ajaxcart>
    </rewrite>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <ajaxcart>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Feliu_Ajaxcart before="Mage_Checkout" >Feliu_Ajaxcart</Feliu_Ajaxcart>
                </modules>
                <frontName>ajaxcart</frontName>
            </args>
        </ajaxcart>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

The checkout.xml (it is a lot of code, so I omitted a lot of lines):

```
<default>

    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="header">
        <block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart_content" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.cart_promotion" as="cart_promotion" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Mini-cart promotion block</label>
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
   ...
</default>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your xml, you can see the line

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart_content" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml">
```

With block `name="minicart_content"`, so you can use this name to get content of that block. This is the default block magento uses to return when action `ajaxUpdate` is called to update minicart section in header.
Refer `Mage_Checkout_CartController::ajaxUpdateAction()`

So in your case below code should work for you.

```
$sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate("checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml");
$sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
```

in place of below,

```
$sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
$sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
```

Comment: it's still null

Comment: check with updated code. The issue is because the block with name `cart_sidebar` or `minicart_content` is not defined in your layout.

Comment: If they are defined than there should not be any issue. can you add both blocks xml code to your question.

Comment: I added the checkout.xml, at least the first part because it's too long

Comment: Please review updated answer @Alex

Comment: Yes, it should work, but I still got 'null'... I see it must be a problem of definition. I have the cache disabled and I still delete the cache very often, so I'm sure it is not cache.

Comment: The last thing you can use is `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate("checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml")`

Comment: The 'Mage::app()->...' returns me undefined instead of 'null'

Comment: Finally it worked, the only change made by me was including '<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>' in the '<default>' handle of the local.xml, it seems that the handles of the catalog.xml that have it are not enough. Thanks for your help.